# SOIC-8 package size error

Tags: operational-amplifier, soic

I designed a PCB using both NE5532 and OP177 opamps. In principle both opamps are in SOIC-8 packages. However when I received the opamps, I found the NE5532 are much larger than the footprint they were designed to have on the PCB (using the KiCad SOIC-8 3.9x4.9mm footprint).

If I measure the width of the NE5532 it appears to be wider than 5mm, while the datasheet says it shouldn't be wider than 4mm.

What has gone wrong here? Have I made a bad assumption somewhere? Or is this a faulty package?

The NE5532 I ordered is [this](https://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/texas-instruments/ne5532apsr/?qs=Tv815z3GeNT4dhpqaaa6LA%3D%3D), and the OP177 is [this](https://nl.mouser.com/ProductDetail/analog-devices-inc/op177gsz/?qs=WIvQP4zGani247KR4WpUjQ%3D%3D), both from Mouser.

Here's the OP177 (top) and NE5532 (bottom), both in "SOIC-8" packages:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the NE5532APSR dimensional drawing from [its data sheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne5532a.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1638627277833&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.co.uk%252F): -

[image]

This is the OP177GSZ dimensional drawing from [its data sheet](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/609/OP177-1504382.pdf): -

[image]

Can you see the difference now?

Comment: Yep, someone didn't read the suffix properly. Thanks!

Comment: We've all done it at some time or other if it's any consolation @SimonCoop